# toggle div to move right/left

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

this is my first question on this website! :)
I am working on a website for a restaurant. The problem is that the following part of my code is malfunctioning. When clicked on the button, #menu expands towards right and stops after width=225px. But when I click the same button again, #menu contracts (width=50) and again expands (width=225)!
Please help!

```
$("#menu").toggle(

     function(){
           $("#menu").animate({width:225},"slow");
    },
    function(){
           $("#menu").animate({width:50},"slow");
    });
        });
});
```

---

```
<!--following is the code for menu-->
<div id="menu" style="position:absolute; width:50; 

opacity:.4; height:75%; background-color:#000000; left:80%; top:20%;">
<button>Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you WANT it to do? We aren't mind readers, unfortunately.

Comment: Greetings! You might want to use Code Sample by clicking `{}` icon to format your code first.

Comment: Aside from the superfluous `});`, your code works fine. Seems that whatever issue you're having, it's been edited out of the question. Please provide more of your code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("button").click(function(){
     $("#menu").toggle(
    function(){
    $("#menu").animate({width:225},"slow");
    },
    function(){
    $("#menu").animate({width:60},"slow");  
    });
    });
   }); 
  </script>

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. The above part of the code has some problems. I want the 'menu' to slide rightwards when I press on the button. It works as expected. Also, I want the menu to slide back as it was before when I press the same button. Unfortunately, it slides to the left and back to the right side again. It is not coming to its original state. Sorry for my naive status. It has been a few days since I have started. I would appreciate your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think that jquery is having trouble with the integers use a string with px in it

```
$('#menu').toggle('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'225px'},500);
},function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'50px'},500);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry Jacob, the code you suggested dint work. jQuery is not working if I make those changes.